# In which clause does 'How' of "How do you think I feel" belong?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, questions, subordinate-clauses

> (1) *How do you think I feel?*

Semantically, (1) asks the listener's opinion about how the speaker feels. So it's syntactically natural that the verb *think* has as its complement a subordinate clause *I feel ___*, where the gap is linked to *How*, and therefore that *do you think* is the superordinate clause (or matrix clause).

Where does all this put *How*? Does it belong in the subordinate clause because it's linked to the gap in the clause? Or does it belong in the superordinate clause along with *do you think*? Or does it belong in another superordinate clause higher than *do you think*?

Comment: Compare "What did you think he wanted?" or "What did he tell you he wanted?" Although I don't pretend to know all the terminology in every schema for English grammar.

Comment: Question Formation (which causes the fronting of _how_ here) is a non-cyclic movement rule, and therefore can extract relative pronouns from deep within the sentence and move them over variable structures (but never [islands](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html)) towards the sentence beginning.

Comment: @StuartF Both of your examples present exactly the same problem as (1) in that _What_ is semantically linked to the subordinate clause _he wanted_ but is fronted before the superordinate clause _did you think_ and _did he tell you_, respectively. That is, I could have asked the same question using either of your examples instead of (1), or better yet also included your examples as well.

Comment: There is no clause and no constituent "*do you think*", and on that basis there is no superordinate or matrix clause "*do you think*" either. As you note, the subordinate clause here is a complement of the verb *know* and is thus an integral part of the actual matrix clause "*do you think I feel*" (or "*How do you think I feel*", depending on which team you support).

Comment: Or, of course, "*you think I feel*".

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think I speak the same grammar language as you, but . . . 
(subordinate clauses are **bolded** below, with *that*-clause *that*s added for clarity):

*You think **that I feel sad**.*

*Do you think **that I feel sad**?*

*You think **that I feel [how]**.*

***[How]** do you think **that I feel ___**?*

Summary: *How* is part of the subordinate clause. If you swap in *what* for *how* and a noun for the adjective *sad*, it might be easier to see.

Comment: That's what I thought, initially. I understand how _how_ is part of the subordinate clause in _You think that I feel [how]_ because it resides after the clause boundary right before _that_. What I don't understand is how _How_ is still part of the subordinate clause even after it's fronted. I think you agree that _do you think_ is higher than _that I feel_. Now, if _How_ were to be at the same level as _that I feel_, I think it should be below _do you think_ somehow, and therefore that there should be a clause boundary right after _How_. But I can't seem to argue that there is one.

Comment: This is the problem Ross worked on in [his dissertation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html). Note, incidentally, that inclusion of the complementizer renders the sentence ungrammatical (*_How do you think that I feel?_) for many speakers. That's because a _that_-complement is an island for them, but not without the _that_.

Comment: @JohnLawler If he came up with an answer, could you tell me what that answer is?

Comment: @JK2 Probably not. His answer was that such long-distance rules have limits and can't cross certain structural boundaries, which he called "islands". But this was in a generative derivational theory, where one structure is related to another by generative rules, like these movement rules. If you don't want the rules, you don't get the solution.

Comment: @JohnLawler Re *_How do you think that I feel?_, is this also ungrammatical? _How do you think that governments should address abortion, if at all?_ https://www.nytimes.com/2021/09/30/learning/what-is-your-reaction-to-the-state-of-abortion-rights-in-2021.html

Comment: @JK2 As I said, that's only an issue for some people. You speak your language and you make your choices. And I've pointed you to resources if you want to learn more, so I will follow the directions and avoid lengthy discussion here.